# Java RegEx replace all characters in string except for a word

Tags: java, regex

I am using the code in Java:

```
String word = "hithere";
String str = "123hithere12345hi";
output(str.replaceAll("(?!"+word+")", "x"));
```

However, rather than outputting: `xxxhitherexxxxxxx` like I want it to, it outputs: `x1x2x3hxixtxhxexrxex1x2x3x4x5xhxix x`, I've tried a load of different regex patterns to try to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this :(
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier without a regex. Just search for each occurrence of `hitthere` (using basic String methods) and replace everything else with `x`.

Comment: It has to be done in one line, with regex.. somehow

Comment: Must be homework... good luck.

Comment: It is not actually homework, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Then why _must_ you use regex if it's not a homework assignment? Simple String methods are the way to go in this situation.

Comment: I added an answer but it's not perfect.  I would agree with most of the other members here, replaceAll() is not gonna go far with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this technically works. Using only replace all and only one line, and it's assuming you string does not contain a deprecated ASCII character (BEL)

```
String string = "hithere";
String string2 = "asdfasdfasdfasdfhithereasasdf";
System.out.println(string2.replaceAll(string,"" + (char)string.length()).replaceAll("[^" + (char)string.length() + "]", "x").replaceAll("" + (char)string.length(), string));
```

Comment: That worked nicely with a slight modification, I had to change the first `string` to `string.replaceAll("\\+", "\\\\+")` to allow for `+`s in the variable `word` (I know it is misnamed). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, if I'm not mistaken:

```
String pattern = "(\\d)|(hi$)";
System.out.println("123hithere12345hi".replaceAll(pattern, "X"));
```

The pattern replaces any numeric digits and the word "hi".

Answer (score 0):

This lookaround based code will work for you:

```
String word = "hithere";
String string = "123hithere12345hi";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(
               ".(?=.*?\\Q" + word + "\\E)|(?<=\\Q" + word + "\\E(.){0,99}).", "x"));
//=> xxxhitherexxxxxxx
```